# How can I reward players for doing research and reading lots of books?

Tags: dnd-5e

One of my players basically spends all of their free time doing research and reading. Are there any cool and interesting ways to reward this player for doing research and reading random books?

Comment: Could you clarify if you mean that the **Player** reads books, providing knowledge and insight into the D&D universe. Or, that the **Player's Character** reads books in their spare time in the game.

Comment: I'm rolling this back to an earlier revision. The edit just now was making assumptions about what the asker meant, despite receiving no confirmation of that information yet. If and when the asker returns, they can confirm that information, *then* we can update the question to clarify. If the asker never returns there's no point reopening and answering the question. Until then, we can wait and see. If someone is raring to see or provide an answer about research-based character rewards, I invite them to ask (and optionally self-answer) about the topic in a new question. (@PeregrineLennert FYI)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose FYI ^

Comment: @Ladifas See above comment, FYI ^

Comment: If someone *does* cover that topic effectively, we may instead close this question as a duplicate of that new question so as to provide this asker with that information in anticipation of their return. In the event they clarify it is in fact the *player* who's doing the research they want to reward, we'd look at updating and reopening this question.

Comment: What sort of books are they reading? How is their acquired knowledge making the game better for them / you / the other players?

Comment: @doppelgreener I've re-edited to correct grammatical errors and summarise it, but have left the inherent ambiguity.